# jmeter showing reference error when i choose java as my scripting language

Tags: webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am getting this error message while running jmeter with webdriver plugin in java language. jmeter version 3.0 webdriver plugin version 1.4.0. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?295710-Production-issue-(-quot-importPackage-quot-is-not-defined-in-lt-eval-gt-at-line-number-1)) help? I.e., is the file UTF8?

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer yes the file is UTF-8.

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK here is the jmeter log [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6PHYOAdkSZzbVhTT25XVFZDWk0/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the WebDriver Sampler, I suggest reporting it via [jmeter-plugins forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins)

The reason is [Nashorn JavaScript engine which cannot longer support loading Java packages into the global scope like](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) `importPackage(java.lang.whatever);`

So if the issue annoys you you can downgrade to Java 7 Server JRE or JDK. Steps:

1. Download [Java 7 Server JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html) or [Java 7 SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and install it to some folder. I would recommend choosing the folder so full path won't contain white spaces or special characters
2. Set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to JDK/JRE 7 installation folder like:

   - for Windows: `set JAVA_HOME=c:\java`
   - for Linux/MacOSX: `JAVA_HOME=/opt/java && export JAVA_HOME`
3. Amend `PATH` environment variable to have "bin" folder of JRE/JDK in the beginning like:

   - for Windows: `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`
   - for Linux/MacOSX: `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH && export PATH`
4. Run JMeter from that console session where you have set the aforementioned variables
5. Enjoy

Once you done with tests development and debugging I would suggest switching back to Java 8 for the load test execution. Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks